# How do I create my own Runescape private server?

Tags: runescape

I want to create my own Runescape server for me and my friends to play on. I've looked at a couple of sites an I haven't found any downloadable source code. Where can I find the source code for the server and where can I find it for the client? Is it even possible to make your own private server without doing all the decompiling yourself?

Comment: I am not sure if this question belongs to this site. Maybe gamedev.se? Not quite sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is impossible to host a Runescape private server, because the source code is not (nor does Jagex have any reason to make it) publically available, for either client *or* server. (And in fact, trying to do so would go against the Jagex TOS)

Runescape generates revenue from monthly subscriptions, so there's little reason to think that "private" servers not hosted by Jagex will ever be available, and deassembling the source code is all kinds of shady legal, so I'd advise against trying to do so.

If you want to play with your friends, you'll just have to do it on Jagex's own servers.

Comment: A quick googling shows that it is in fact possible to host a private runescape server, and that there are quite a few of them. However, at the very least, doing this would violate the EULA and most likely a good chunk of copyright law. I think this question should be closed for being both a semi-gamedev question, and a piracy question.

Comment: @Fambida I think it's ok that the question is about an illegal activity because we've provided the ethical answer. It's a good reference for other people who are thinking the same thing. I wouldn't want to arrest somebody who asks, "How do I find cocaine?" I'd explain the harmful health effects of cocaine and that it's illegal. Plus, contracts, laws and social expectations can change. If hosting a private Runescape server becomes acceptable in the future, we can simply change the answer, instead of undeleting the question.